# Singleton class, GraphicsManager and static

Tags: c++, singleton, sdl, sdl-2

I am trying to make a framework using **SDL 2.0** and **O-OP**.

Here I have a **CGraphicsManager** class:

```
namespace tde {
    class CGraphicsManager : public Singleton<CGraphicsManager>
    {
    private:
        static SDL_Window* mWindow;
        static SDL_Renderer* mRenderer;

    public:
        ~CGraphicsManager();

        static Uint32 Init(const char* title, Vector2i& size, Uint32 flags);
        static SDL_Window* getWindow(){ return mWindow; }
        static SDL_Renderer* getRenderer() { return mRenderer; }
    };
}
```

And when I try to do so:

```
SDL_RenderClear(Graphics.getRenderer());
```

The compiler says:

error C2248: Singleton::Singleton can't reach private member in Singleton<'tde::CGraphicsManager'>

I tried to make mWindow and mRenderer static members but this way don't work. Help me to store window and renderer somehow in this sistem to make them visible and avalible in **tde** namespace!

Comment: Where is your declaration of `Graphics`?

Comment: Or more specifically, can you show us how you're declaring `Graphics`?

Comment: "#define Graphics tde::CGraphicsManager::getInstance()"
It is in "Root.h" in global namespace. define works perfect for CRoot class.
Here is a link to complete Root.h: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ox2hvhqwo28jhfd/Singleton_SDL_static__Root.h.txt

Comment: And what are you using to get the definition of `Singleton`?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/d0lgo0b97lqspiq/Singleton_SDL_static__Singleton.h.txt

Comment: I think you need to make these methods and members non-static.

Comment: This title is so wrong. Please stop whatever you are doing. Read up on Singleton pattern and why you shouldn't use it.

Comment: I should point out that there are valid reasons for using singletons.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons

Comment: @Peter This problem is not one of them, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, to make it all work required a bit of reading...  This [Boost singleton page](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/pool/doc/implementation/singleton.html) suggested to me that the inheriting class needs to have a public default constructor, despite it being a Singleton.

The following code example compiles.  Note the changes I made to `Singleton` and `CGraphicsManager`:

```
template<typename T>
class Singleton
{
    protected:
    Singleton() { };
    Singleton(const T&);
    Singleton& operator=(const T&);

    public:

    static T& getInstance() {
        static T instance;
        return instance;
    }

    ~Singleton() { };
};

namespace tde
{
    class CGraphicsManager : public Singleton<CGraphicsManager>
    {
    private:
        SDL_Window* mWindow;
        SDL_Renderer* mRenderer;

    public:
        CGraphicsManager() { } 
        ~CGraphicsManager() { };

        unsigned Init(const char* title, unsigned& size, unsigned flags);
        SDL_Window* getWindow(){ return mWindow; }
        SDL_Renderer* getRenderer() { return mRenderer; }
    };
}
```

I gave `Singleton::Singleton()` and `Singleton::~Singleton()` trivial implementations.  I also made all these methods `protected` instead of `private`, so the inheriting class can invoke them.

I made all the methods and members in `CGraphicsManager` non-static.  And, I gave `CGraphicsManager::CGraphicsManager()` and `CGraphicsManager::~CGraphicsManager()` trivial implementations also.

This compiles now, and `Graphics.getRenderer()` appears to do the right thing.

After all that, I question the value of inheriting from the `Singleton<>` template class.  The usual way I implement a Singleton is to just embed these methods directly, or use a friend function that has a `static` local, rather than outsourcing it to a parent class.  Most of the issues seem to revolve around method visibility between parent and child in the inheritance hierarchy.